# How to delete the cache from UIWebview or dealloc UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Every time I load a new page with `UIWebView` the before loaded page is shown for a short time.

How can I clear that cache? Another possibility would be to dealloc `UIWebview`. I tried that but than my `UIWebView` is always "empty". How should the `alloc` and `dealloc` be done in this case?

I noticed that the `UIWebView` is consuming about 10 MB RAM. Now the `UIWebView` is loaded together with the `ViewController`. And the view is autoreleased as well as the `UIWebView` is autoreleased. Wouldn't it be better to dealloc the WebView each time?

**Solution:**

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
}

- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
    self.webView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to create the `UIWebView` programmatically on `viewWillAppear:` and to release it on `viewDidDisappear:`, like this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:exampleFrame] autorelease];
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.webView.autoresizingMask = webViewBed.autoresizingMask;
    [exampleView addSubview:self.webView];
}
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    self.webView = nil;
}
```

If you do this and your `UIWebView` doesn't get released you should check it's retain count and understand who is retaining it.

Comment: What is exampleFrame, webViewBed and exampleView? What is autoresizingMask? I don't implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol so I don't need the delegate. `addSubview` don't work for me, because my `UIViewController` does not support this. As far as I can see you are not releasing the web view on `viewDidDisappear`. You only remove it from the superview and set it to `nil`. I tried your approach and I only can see a white screen. I edited my question so you can see my code.

Comment: exampleFrame is just the size of the UIWebView you are creating.
webViewBed shouldn't be a part of this example, it's not useful in this context.
exampleView is the view you're adding the UIWebView to.

And of course, you addSubview()s to Views, not to view controllers. So you'll have to do something like [viewController.view addSubview:...].
I am releasing the webview, it's a property (see the "self."?) so you can set it to nil and it'll be released.

Comment: Perfect!!
This is the only solution on the internet that i found to be working!!

Answer (score 28):

I had nearly the same problem. I wanted the webview cache to be cleared, because everytime i reload a local webpage in an `UIWebView`, the old one is shown. So I found a solution by simply setting the `cachePolicy` property of the request. Use a `NSMutableURLRequest` to set this property. With all that everything works fine with reloading the `UIWebView`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:MyHTMLFilePath]; 
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
 [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
 [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this did not solve my problem for whatever reason.  i'm guessing it's a bug in the API.

Comment: Thanks: "removeAllCachedResponses" did not work for me but this did.

Comment: What about if I'm using loadHtmlString? How can I clear the cache every time I loadHtmlString?

Comment: Only with [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData]; and [_webView loadRequest:request]; my UIWebView did not reload the page. I had to add [_webView reload];

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove all cached responses, you may also want to try something like this:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Answer (score 2):

If I had to make a guess your property for webView is

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Correct? The important part is the retain.

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
```

The above code allocates a UIWebView (meaning retainCount = 1) and then adds it to self.webView, where it is retained again (retainCount = 2).

Change the code to the following, and your webView should be deallocated.

```
self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
```

---

addSubview: can only be called on UIViews.

```
//[self.navigationController addSubview:self.webView];
```

should be

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Comment: You're right. But I don't understand that why the retain count of 2 causes the webview to display a white screen. Thank you for your help. Whom should I give the check mark? It's difficult ...

Comment: I don't know what or even if the white screen has something to do with this issue. But if you have memory management issues left it's complicated to debug other problems. So first fix the memory management and investigate further into the white screen issue.

Answer (score 2):

I did something simpler, I just set the webView's `alpha` to 0 on loadRequest and 1 on webViewDidFinishLoad.

```
thewebview.alpha=0.0;
thewebview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[thewebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url(str)]];
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    thewebview.alpha=1.0;
}
```

(Actually I have a fade-in, as rendering f.ex. a PDF can take 1/5 seconds or so.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also load @"about:blank" after the webview disappears, then it will be empty the next time you access it.