# How to delete the cache in UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I have loaded the url in `webview`, loading is successful but whenever I hit again its show two url in cache and again its show three url etc. it means it continues to maintain the stack. I am using a lot of method but not working properly.

**These are following what i am trying till now.**

**1.**

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];


[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {

    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
}
}
```

**2.**

```
int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

**3.**

```
 NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];
```

**4.**

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];

[self.webView removeFromSuperview];
self.webView.delegate = nil;
self.webView = nil;
}
```

**5.**

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
```

**6.**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self.webView stopLoading];
}
- (void) stopLoading {
[self.webView stopLoading];
self.webView.delegate = nil;
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *homeIndexUrl = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"Home" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:homeIndexUrl];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlReq];
[EALoaderView hideLoaderForView:self.view animated:YES];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
 }
```

**I have also try from these following Answer.**

1.[Clearing UIWebview cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache)

2.[NSURLProtocol isn't asked to load after YES response to canInitWithRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390036/nsurlprotocol-isnt-asked-to-load-after-yes-response-to-caninitwithrequest/26408420#26408420)

3.[How To Clear A UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576154/how-to-clear-a-uiwebview)

4.[How to delete the cache from UIWebview or dealloc UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683576/how-to-delete-the-cache-from-uiwebview-or-dealloc-uiwebview)

5.[How to clear UIWebView cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523435/how-to-clear-uiwebview-cache)

6.[UIwebview without Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744644/uiwebview-without-cache)

I am doing a lot of R&D but not found the exact solution to resolve these things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code bellow to delete cache, wish it works for you:

```js
//This must be called in Main Thread
+ (void)clearWebCache
{
 //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289838/how-to-delete-wkwebview-cookies
    //https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105094/how-to-remove-cache-in-wkwebview/32491271#32491271
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
        NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache,
                                                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeOfflineWebApplicationCache,
                                                        WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache,
                                                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeLocalStorage,
                                                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeCookies,
                                                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeSessionStorage,
                                                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeIndexedDBDatabases,
                                                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeWebSQLDatabases
                                                        ]];
        //// All kinds of data
        //            NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes];
        //// Date from
        NSDate *dateFrom = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
        //// Execute
        [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:websiteDataTypes modifiedSince:dateFrom completionHandler:^{
            // Done
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hayia, Fellows! 
researched this theme for a while and found a solution that works for me the best - use WKWebView it doesn't leak! 
That's it - so simple.